# Microsoft Exchange Site Replication Service Exchange 2003 server

Tags: exchange-2003

Is Microsoft Exchange Site Replication Service on Exchange 2003 Server needed to be started even if you only have one exchange server in the domain?

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't. Furthermore it's only required in a mixed mode Exchange 5.5\2000 or Exchange 5.5\2003 organization.